# catkin_make: catkin_pkg.package not found (anaconda)

Tags: ros, ros2, catkin, anaconda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unable to solve this problem. I tried to run catkin_make command in catkin_ws directory.

```
yograj@yograj-Inspiron-5537:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/yograj/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/yograj/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/yograj/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/yograj/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/yograj/anaconda2/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named catkin_pkg.package
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/yograj/anaconda2/bin/python
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/yograj/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:151 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/yograj/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/yograj/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281598/catkin_make:-catkin_pkg.package-not-found-(anaconda)/) by [Nebula](https://answers.ros.org/users/33043/nebula/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved by following similar [problem.](https://answers.ros.org/question/247794/catkin-cmake-error-with-ros-error-code-1/?comment=281602#post-id-281602)

with using

```
pip install -U rosdep rosinstall_generator wstool rosinstall six vcstools
```

---

Originally posted by [Nebula](https://answers.ros.org/users/33043/nebula/) with karma: 98 on 2018-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From @tfoote's answer for a [very similar question](https://answers.ros.org/question/263430/install-ros-kinetic-with-anacondaminiconda/):

> to use Anaconda you will need to do a
> lot with your PYTHONPATH to make sure
> that all dependencies are on the path
> that Anaconda's interpreter is using.
>
> I would recommend trying to find a way
> to use anaconda separately/in parallel
> with your anaconda installation. The
> main problem is that Anaconda doesn't
> use the standard installed python
> libraries so often you end up with
> missing resources.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nebula](https://answers.ros.org/users/33043/nebula/) on 2018-02-02**:
I solved by following similar [problem](https://answers.ros.org/question/247794/catkin-cmake-error-with-ros-error-code-1/?comment=281602#post-id-281602).

with using

```
pip install -U rosdep rosinstall_generator wstool rosinstall six vcstools
```

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-02**:
Great, but please don't use a *comment* to provide an *answer*, that's what answers are for.